# distutils.core not found after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, upgrade, 22.04, python3

I am trying to install a local directory as a package in python using a `setup.py` file. However, when I run `python3.8 setup.py install` I obtain the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'disutils.core'`.

I work in a `venv` with Python3.8 and tried using `sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils` already resulting in the message

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-distutils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-distutils'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-distutils'
```

when I run `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` the installation is succesful, but it does not solve my `distutils.core` missing module error. This is probably since `python3-distutils` is pointing to the distutils version for Python3.10 (`3.10.4-0ubuntu1`).

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, did not experience this error before on 20.04...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to `Python3.10` in my virtual environment solved this issue.